# Sublime Text 3 LatexTools "Sorry, but texify did not succeed."

Tags: miktex, sublime-text, latextools

I made an update of my miktex packages `MiKTeX update (admin)`.

Now with Sublime Text 3 and LaTeXTools I get the message

```
2015-12-14 18:41:15,276+0100 FATAL texify - MiKTeX encountered an internal error.
2015-12-14 18:41:15,276+0100 FATAL texify - Info: 
2015-12-14 18:41:15,276+0100 FATAL texify - Source: Programs\MiKTeX\texify\mcd.cpp
2015-12-14 18:41:15,276+0100 FATAL texify - Line: 1168
```

Compiling with texworks works well.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
test file
\end{document}
```

Anybody encountering the same issues with fresh updated miktex and LaTeXTools?

---

### Edit

I just opened an issue for LaTeXTools, because I suppose it is a LaTeXTools problem. [link](https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools/issues/627)

Comment: This seems to be a problem with LaTeXTools rather than TeX/LaTeX specifically, so I'd suggest you report it on their github page (but someone did while I was writing this comment: https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools/issues/627). I'm not sure its "on topic" here...

Answer (score 1):

I reinstalled miktex and then got the `COULD NOT CPOMPILE` message from Sublime Text 3.

After reading the hint to use the `reconfigure LaTeXTools...` functionality I used it and now it works.